# My Bluetooth 4.2 device isn't showing in the list of available devices not in Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

Since I upgraded my Ubuntu system to the latest version, I encountered this problem of my 4.2 Bluetooth headphones not showing on the list of ready to pair devices, noting that the headphones are working and they're ready to pair

Comment: Install updates and shut down the computer, then boot it up.  There was another person with the same issue and it just fixed itself